# How to load more than one json file in angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I am wondering how to load multiple .json files in to template.
In my example I have submissions from users and I do not want to store everything in one json file if possible.

How to grab some data from multiple json files?

here is my **[plunk example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KMPmSE0rYzaumE32lcig?p=preview)**

I want to load users.json as well

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('contentItem', function ($compile,$parse) {

    templates = {
      image: 'image.html',
      event: 'event.html',
      article: 'article.html',
      ad: 'ad.html',
      discount: 'discount.html',
      video: 'video.html'

    }

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.setUrl = function(){
          return templates[scope.content.content_type];
        }

    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: {
          content: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    };
});

function ContentCtrl($scope, $http) {
    "use strict";

    $scope.url = 'content.json';
    $scope.content = [];

    $scope.fetchContent = function() {
        $http.get($scope.url).then(function(result){
            $scope.content = result.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.fetchContent();
}
```

Help appreciated

Comment: you can have one more http call. You do not want that?

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request for JSON either from the controller like:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.users = [];  
     $scope.getUsers = function() {        
            $http({method: 'JSONP', url: "users.json?query=?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query="+ $scope.searchString}).
              success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.users = data;
              }).
              error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data || "Request failed");
            });     
};
```

and the other approach (better one) would be to make use of angular factory to fetch the JSON file.

```
myApp.factory('getUsersFactory',['$http',function($http){
   return {
     getUsers: function(callback){
       $http({method: 'JSONP', url: "users.json?query=?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query="+ $scope.searchString}).success(callback);
     }
   }
}]);
```

where now you can include this factory as a dependency and get the user data and assign that in the callback function.

Comment: Hi I must be doing something wrong... as I am unable to load json file...

I also want to continue existing loading method.

Is there a way to something like this?



function ContentCtrl($scope, $http) {
    "use strict";
    
    $scope.content = [];
    $scope.users = [];

    $scope.fetchContent = function() {
        $http.get('content.json').then(function(result){
            $scope.content = result.data;
        });
        $http.get('users.json').then(function(result){
            $scope.users = result.data;
        });
    }
    
    $scope.fetchContent();
}

Comment: yes this is also possible but dont you think that separate functions would be an advantage to keep code segragation

Comment: I am not sure which method will perform better. If using seperate functions is more flexable then I am happy to use factories.

Comment: Yes it is and using factories you do not have to use $apply calls